# how to import mathjax in vue as local dependency?

Tags: javascript, vue.js, import, module, dependency-management

im using vue-mathjax in my project and in the readme it says to use cdn of mathJax
works fine with the CDN version

im need to use mathJax(v. 2.7.2) as local as dependency for my project but dont know how to import it with the correct configurations

how do yout set the configuration same as with the cdn version?

**CDN**

```
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/mathjax/2.7.2/MathJax.js?config=TeX-AMS_HTML"></script>
```

**Local import after installing with npm**

```
//main.js
import '../node_modules/mathjax/MathJax?config=TeX-AMS_HTML'
```

**error**

```
Uncaught SyntaxError: Unexpected token '<'
```

repo - https://github.com/qwtfy/mathjax-test

Answer (score 1):

If you're able to switch to the new **version 3**, here are the steps assuming you already have **vue-mathjax**.

1. Install MathJax from npm: `npm install mathjax@3`
2. Move the MathJax's es5 directory to a public directory: `mv node_modules/mathjax/es5/ src/assets/mathjax/`
3. Import the component config you want, for example:

```
import '../assets/mathjax/es5/tex-chtml.js';
```

If you must stick with **version 2.7.x**, you'll need to do the following. In my testing, it was less stable.

1. Install MathJax 2.7.9 from npm: `npm install --save mathjax@2.7.9`
2. Move **MathJax.js** (located at node_modules/mathjax/MathJax.js) to a public directory like **assets**.
3. Move **TeX-AMS_HTML.js** (located at node_modules/mathjax/config/TeX-AMS_HTML.js)  to the same public diretory.
4. Import both files inside your component, in order:

```
import '../assets/MathJax.js'
import '../assets/TeX-AMS_HTML.js';
```

Here it is working for me:

[image]

Full single file component example using v3 and vue-mathjax.

```
<template lang='pug'>
  div
    b-container(style='width: 40%')
      b-textarea(v-model='formula' cols='30' rows='10')
      p output
      vue-mathjax(:formula='formula')
</template>

<script lang="ts">
import { Component, Vue } from 'vue-property-decorator';
import { VueMathjax } from 'vue-mathjax';
import '../assets/mathjax/es5/tex-chtml.js';

@Component({
  components: {
    'vue-mathjax': VueMathjax,
  },
})

export default class HelloWorld extends Vue {
  formula = '$$x = {-b \\pm \\sqrt{b^2-4ac} \\over 2a}.$$';
}
</script>
```

Documentation of these steps can be found [here](https://www.npmjs.com/package/mathjax#hosting-your-own-copy-of-the-mathjax-components) and [here](http://docs.mathjax.org/en/v2.7-latest/configuration.html#loading-and-configuring-mathjax).

Comment: i followed your steps and it does render at first but after some time error occurs "Math Processing Error"

Comment: i have made a repo with the error. if u could take a look it would be much appreciated